# Function returns array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, position

I have this class:

```
class Dados{

function cadastro($store){
preg_match_all('#<div align=\'left\'>(.*?)</div>#s',$store,$dados);

return $dados[1];

}}
```

And this is the output of `print_r($dados->cadastro($pagina_cadastro));`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 02A      
    [1] => M        
    [2] => 72 - CIÊNCIA DA COMPUTAÇÃO/N
    [3] => 1402
    [4] => 23/12/2013
    [5] => 6/7/1995
    [6] => S
    [7] => M
    [8] => Details Removed                         
    [9] => Details Removed           
    [10] => Details Removed
    [11] => Details Removed                               
    [12] => Details Removed
    [13] => Details Removed
    [14] => My Email
    [15] => Details Removed
    [16] =>               
    [17] => Details Removed       
    [18] => Details Removed       
)
```

- Details were removed to protect my privacy

So the question is, how can use echo to print just positions 3, 7 and 9 (for example) ?
I already try `$dados->cadastro[1]($pagina_cadastro);` and `$dados->cadastro($pagina_cadastro)[1];` but any works.

I think it's a newbie question but I really need help.
Thank you so much!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? What if you do `$dados = $dados->cadastro$pagina_cadastro); echo $dados[1];`?

Comment: Hi, I'm running PHP 5.3, using your method works, but is there any other solution ? I'm not like to declare another variable just for this. Thank you!

Comment: There is no other solution. You could upgrade your PHP version and use `$dados->cadastro($pagina_cadastro)[1];`

Comment: Hi, I can upgrade what version support this syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result to a variable first:

```
$details = $dados->cadastro($pagina_cadastro);
```

and then you can get any position you want by:

```
echo $details[3];
echo $details[7];
echo $details[9];
```

Answer (score 0):

may be try like this:

```
$val = $dados->cadastro($pagina_cadastro);

echo $val[3];// similarly other also.
```

Answer (score 0):

if this

```
<?php 
    class Dados{

        function cadastro($store){
             preg_match_all('#<div align=\'left\'>(.*?)</div>#s',$store,$dados);
             return $dados[1];

        }
     }

     $var = new Dados();

     print_r(var->cadastro());
?>
```

returns your array.

Then you do like this

```
<?php
    //Previous code before this
    $array = var->cadastro();
    echo $array[7] . $array[9]; //etc
?>
```

To specify specific values

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your function call to a variable like this:

```
$var = $dados->cadastro($pagina_cadastro);
```

Then you can print any index of the array like this :

```
print $var[3];
print $var[7];
print $var[9];
```